# Spurious comma before Series Number in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

When formatting a citation that has a `series` and `number` (i.e., a book that is part of a numbered book series) using `biblatex-chicago`, I find that an extra comma is added right after the series title and before the contents of `number` whenever the latter is a list or a range.

There is no such problem when the `number` field contains a simple integer.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{biblatex-source-division}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Graf:GCAL,
    Address = {Vatican City},
    Author = {Graf, Georg},
    Number = {118, 133, 146, 147, 172},
    Publisher = {Biblioteca Apostolica Vaticana},
    Series = {Studi e Testi},
    Shorttitle = {GCAL},
    Title = {Geschichte der christlichen arabischen Literatur},
    Volumes = {5},
    Year = {1944--1953}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Graf:GCAL}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `\cite` command produces

> Georg Graf, *Geschichte der christlichen arabischen Literatur*, 5 vols., Studi e Testi, 118, 133, 146, 147, 172 (Vatican City: Biblioteca Apostolica Vaticana, 1944–1953)

Correct output would be:

> Georg Graf, *Geschichte der christlichen arabischen Literatur*, 5 vols., Studi e Testi 118, 133, 146, 147, 172 (Vatican City: Biblioteca Apostolica Vaticana, 1944–1953)

The only difference is the comma after "Studi e Testi."

The same happens when the `number` field contains a range (e.g., `3--5`) but not for entries with dots (e.g., `20.1`) or Roman numerals (e.g., `II.1`).

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of an `\ifnumeral` test in the `sernum` field format. It's false when there are commas in the `number` field.

We can change the test to `\ifnumerals` which will be true in your case.

Also instead of `year={1944--1953}` you should use `date={1944/1953}`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{biblatex-source-division}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Graf:GCAL,
    Address = {Vatican City},
    Author = {Graf, Georg},
    Number = {118, 133, 146, 147, 172},
    Publisher = {Biblioteca Apostolica Vaticana},
    Series = {Studi e Testi},
    Shorttitle = {GCAL},
    Title = {Geschichte der christlichen arabischen Literatur},
    Volumes = {5},
    date = {1944/1953}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{sernum}{%
  \ifnumerals{#1}% change from \ifnumeral to \ifnumerals
  {\addnbspace #1}%
  {\addcomma\addspace #1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{Graf:GCAL}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, why is it better to use the `date` field than `year`? I have a lot of entries that use date ranges, so I thought I should ask before converting them all!

Comment: You will see a warning from `biber` when you run it on your original example. `year` is meant to be an integer. It is not meant to take a year range. `date` takes a flexible format including ranges and even times that is then split by `biber` into its component parts. So `date={1944/1953}` ends up as `year={1944}` and `endyear={1953}` in the `bbl` file. See section 2.3.8 in the `biblatex` manual for details on specifying dates.